How do I apply different block supports to different parts of my custom block?
I am developing a custom block for my WordPress plugin.  The block is meant to be very similar to the WordPress core search block.  On the default search block, there are several supports declared, including for border, background color, text color, text size, etc.  This block is able to apply styles and classes from the block supports to different elements in the block.  For example, the background color control only changes the background color of the button, and the font size support only applies to the label above the search input.  I am looking for a solution for how to accomplish this in my block.  My block is a server rendered block using the render.php file, and I am having a hard time finding a convenient and scalable way to use the string returned by get_block_wrapper_attributes() to apply styles only to certain parts of my block.  So, what is the best way to extract specific styles from the block wrapper attributes to apply to specific elements in my custom block's render.php?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You should perhaps split it into several blocks : you can define a template when inserting the parent block to include default children.

Interesting, I may update my block to use this method in the future.  Thank you.  For now, I just manually parsed the block supports based on the way the core search block does it.

I solved this issue when I realized that all style attributes are held in the $attributes array passed to the render.php file.  It is a lot of raw work, but specific styles from block supports can be extracted from this object.  For certain supports, I have to check multiple possible locations in the block supports, and sometimes you will need to convert them from variable names to usable classnames or css vars using regexes, but it is done by parsing through the $attributes array manually :(
